# How do I pass a variable to a template file?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a template that defines a module that builds a paragraph.

This paragraph uses a field reference to link another type of content.

In my main paragraph I call this reference content with

`{{ content.field_hero_slider_item_reference }}` to display it.

This works, but I would like to be able to pass variables to it so that I can style the individual elements inside the reference with attributes from another field, say "settings".

I tried:

`{% include with {'items': content.field_hero_slider_item_reference, 'attrs': attrs} %}`

Unfortunately, there's something that breaks the display mechanism of `{{ }}`, albeit if I call **dsm** or **kint** on any of these variables (attrs or items) I can see exactly what I would need.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if this has enough focus or details, but reference property is handled by the configured field formatter on that entity view display.

Comment: ^ this. Any other peripheral variables would be in a preprocess hook.

Comment: You can dump a variable in twig with `{{ dump(variable) }}`